# NanoHTTPD with deleted requests

Tags: android, nanohttpd

How do I check the operation of the library to perform http delete request. The following code is used to verify the sleduyuschischy

```
@Override
public Response serve(String uri, Method method, Map<String, String> headers, Map<String, String> parms, Map<String, String> files) {

    Log.d(TAG, "serve + method = " + method.name());
    Log.d(TAG, "serve + files = " + files.toString());

    String answer = "";
    try {

        Log.d(TAG, "serve path = " + ROOT + uri);
        FileReader index = new FileReader(ROOT + uri);

        reader = new BufferedReader(index);
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            answer += line;
        }
        reader.close();

    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        Log.w(TAG, "File not found - " + ioe.toString());
    }

    return newFixedLengthResponse(answer);
}
```

following page layout

```
<h2>Hello everyone! </h2>
</br>
<form action="action.php" method="post">
<p>Your name: <input type="text" name="name"/></p>

<p>Your age: <input type="text" name="age"/></p>

<p><input type="submit"/></p>
```

Comment: You can check with method.name() right?

Comment: that will be used method.name () is true, but how do I check? Requests get and post check is still possible, but as this check, but but how do I check in using html forms?

Comment: You are not verifying anything. And i see nothing with delete. And is that html produced when? Please explain your self better.

Comment: I know it's bad, but I need to test the functionality of the server to query delet and try to do it, but do not quite understand how